# A way to see increase in vote count after bounty? Also to sort newly posted answers?

Tags: support, site-attributes, up-votes

- Is There a way to see the increase in vote count per post in a topic which was setup for a bounty?
- Is there a way to sort the answers newly posted.

Comment: "Is there a way to sort answers to newest posted and voted" Do you mean both or mutually exclusive?

Comment: The newest answer posted does go up the stack if it has 0 votes But so do the older answers if they are edited.So i guess it would be only newest answers after the bounty

Answer (score 1):

A user's reputation tab now shows the actual time votes to posts were given, so you could infer it from that.  For example, for the question [Where and how to mention Stackoverflow participation in the résumé?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38597/where-and-how-to-mention-stackoverflow-participation-in-the-resume)

You can look at the [asker's reputation tab](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4443/sandeepan-nath?tab=reputation):

> +5    23:01   upvote
>   +5    10:33   upvote
>   +5    06:49   upvote
>   +5    06:20   upvote
>   +5    06:13   upvote

The [revisions tab](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/38597/revisions) shows when the bounty was added (17 hours ago)

Just click [active](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38597/where-and-how-to-mention-stackoverflow-participation-in-the-resume?tab=active#tab-top) to see the answers by recent activity (sort of what you are asking) or [oldest](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38597/where-and-how-to-mention-stackoverflow-participation-in-the-resume?tab=oldest#tab-top) (the order they were posted, but in reverse, so you'd have to look to the end for the newest answers).  Again, you'd have to infer which is which by the time the bounty was posted.

Comment: +1 for active tab I seem to have missed that.Still it would be nice to see the votes added to each post after the bounty was posted,Near the vote count like view both up and down votes feature.Active here means recently added or edited right? up vote to a post does,t count as activity. The basic idea behind the feature is that to see how new answers are getting votes compare to the already posted answers.